# Shared storage between Workers and Scheduler in Airflow

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to get DAGs from multiple git repositories.

I created a DAG that gets all the repositories, and then clones them locally.

The issue is that the storage of the worker is not the same as the scheduler's, so the scheduler will not pick up these new repos.

How can I have multi-repos synced to Airflow?

Otherwise, how can I have shared storage bewtween workers and scheduler? I tried creating a shared `pvc` but I get `Permission Denied` error when I try to write from the worker.

I'm using the official [Airflow helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/apache-airflow/airflow)

Here is my `pvc` config (to be clear: I can `sudo` and write files in here. But the worker cannot)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: workers-shared-volume
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  storageClassName: efs
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /opt/shared
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: workers-shared-volume-claim
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs
  volumeName: workers-shared-volume
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

This is how I mounted it on the Airflow chart

```yaml
workers:
  extraVolumes:
    - name: &workers-shared-volume workers-shared-volume-claim
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        readOnly: false
        claimName: *workers-shared-volume
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: *workers-shared-volume
      mountPath: /opt/workers-shared-volume
scheduler:
  extraVolumes:
    - name: *workers-shared-volume
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        readOnly: true
        claimName: *workers-shared-volume
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: *workers-shared-volume
      mountPath: /opt/workers-shared-volume
```

Comment: Where did you get the `Permission Denied`? Can you go inside worker pod/container and see if you can access the shared volume? Try also creating new file in that shared volume.

Comment: I got permission denied from the `worker` pod (where I'm doing `git clone`). I haven't tried from the `scheduler` since I set it as `readOnly`. I can `su - root` on both, and at that point I can write

Comment: In this claimName `*workers-shared-volume` in the`PersistentVolumeClaim` object/definition, what is  the `accessModes` value?

Comment: Yes, the volume and the claim are both there (I posted the component deployment file in the question). Access mode is `ReadWriteMany`.

Comment: If you don't  `su - root`, you cannot create file? I think that means airflow is running as a different user and it does not have that RW access. Can you run `whoami` in the container?